# How to combine/merge sheets of two workbook into one workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, xssf

I have two workbooks and each contains one sheet in it. Now I want to combine these two worksheets to one workbook as two sheets using POI and java .

Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Answer (score -2):

you can do it using a library named "aspose"

```
    Workbook sheet1= new Workbook("file1.xlsx");
    Workbook sheet2= new Workbook("file2.xlsx");
 sheet1.combine(sheet2);
sheet1.save("mergedFile.xlsx");
```

And add this dependency into your pom

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspose-cells</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```